# Updating Custom listview item after on resume()

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a custum listview with image, text, a download button and a progress bar for each item.

The plan is that when I click the download button, the progress bar which original is invisible becomes visible and starts to progress, while the download button changes to a cancel button.

But what happens now is that when I minimize the app to home and opens it back up, the listview refreshes(that is the adapter is called again) as the activity resumes. This undos all the states which have been set. 
the progress bar becomes invisible and the download button shows up with the download icon instead of the cancel icon, even though the download continues in Asynctask.

What I need to do is to find a to set the state of the list item, such that the progress bar continues to progress and the button changes to cancel button. i.e to retain the ui state as the download goes on in the Asynctask, even when the listview is reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

I viewed`  your question. The problem is regarding the Asynchronous AsyncTask that you used. I can try to explain you the problem and the recommended solution.

If you start the AsyncTask inside your activity, Now when you close the activity (finish) It is not guaranteed that the running AsyncTask also stop working and finish itself because of your activity is no longer running. That does not happen.

Another fact is that, As previously said that once you fire the AsyncTask you could not reuse it next time when you start the same activity again. In your case, it always starts the new AsyncTask when you open the activity.

Alternative Solution: You can use the Service component that can run in the background (keep in mind that it does not create the separate thread from your application, It's run on the application thread)  means it has no UI and could  be run even if your activity or application is not in front of the user.  You can put your download logic inside it and bind with your running activity.

Regarding the state of the UI in adapter that you can manage by communicating between the activity and running service.

This is simple approach that you can use it.

Hope this will help!

Thanks
Bhavdip